# Given several values of x, y and z in the relation z=ax+by+c, determine a, b and c

Tags: multivalued-functions

I have inherited a cloud pricing mechanism that essentially uses two variables to derive prices. No-one in the organisation knows the original derivation, but I have about 16 sets of datapoints from which I am hoping to reverse-engineer the mechanism. That should help derive new or future pricing - or trigger a change of policy! Hence, given some known values of x, y and z in the relation z=ax+by+c, how might I determine a, b and c? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Although your data set is pretty small, you could still perform a linear regression to find the coefficients giving the best fit

Comment: Thanks — but how do I do that?

Comment: "Thanks — but how do I do that?" If you bother to post the data, I can show it to you step by step, so the next time you'll be able to do it yourself. Or just google "linear regression" and choose the exposition which is easiest for you to read :-)